# Getting errors while installing Phppgadmin

Tags: phppgadmin

"sudo apt-get install phppgadmin"
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
phppgadmin is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 65 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up phppgadmin (5.1-1) ...
 * Reloading web server apache2                                                  * 
 * Apache2 is not running
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "reload" failed.
dpkg: error processing package phppgadmin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 phppgadmin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

What has to be done to remove this error and successfully install the phppgadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting the apache process and then re-run the installation.

Comment: "sudo service apache2 restart "
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.

Comment: apache server is not starting

Comment: it is saying port 80 is already in use, try purging the port and running apache again, or run the process on a different port